# Injecting a Angular Service in the main.ts file

Tags: angular, typescript, service

Currently my *main.ts* file looks like this:

```
declare const require; 
const translations = require("raw-loader!./locale/messages.de.xlf");

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
  providers: [
    { provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: translations },
    { provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: 'xlf' }
  ]
});
```

Instead of hardcoding this `"raw-loader!./locale/messages.de.xlf"` I would like to use a service instead which provides this string, like for example:

```
const translations = require(translationService.localeString); //does not work!
```

Is there a possible way of doing this? I have already created a Service for that but I can't find a way to inject it into the main.ts file.

Comment: I opted for a static method on my service, rather than trying to get this to work - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#static-properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Use the service, we need instance of it. We can create instance without constructor using Injector.

DemoService:

```
@Injectable()
export class DemoService {
  test="hi";
  localeString="abc";
}
```

Main.ts:

```
    import {Injectable, ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';
    var injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([DemoService]);
    var demoService = injector.get(DemoService)
    alert(demoService.test)
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
     providers: [
      { provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: demoService.localeString },
      { provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: 'xlf' }
     ]
    });
```

Now we can use the variableor method of service as i am using inside alert()

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Df6xSxJPaCZVupyMmtUp?p=preview

We don't need service to access the constant values. another recommended way of doing this would be, keep your constant variable in separate file(i.e. environment.ts).

environment.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  localeString: "raw-loader!./locale/messages.de.xlf"
};
```

Modify the main.ts:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
  providers: [
    { provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: environment.localeString },
    { provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: 'xlf' }
  ]
});
```

Comment: This sadly does not work. I get an error saying: _localeString doesnt exist on type "DemoService"_

Comment: we can access  constant directly, to inject through service i am creating a template

Comment: Works without importing Injectable in main.ts

Comment: My "DemoService" has dependencies,
and I get and Error, is there a workaround also for this case?

Comment: `ReflectiveInjector` seems to be deprecated now :(

Answer (score 6):

The solution for Angular 9 (Based on mohit uprim answer):

```
platformBrowserDynamic()
.bootstrapModule(AppModule)
.then(ref => {
  const configService = ref.injector.get(DemoService);
  alert(demoService.test)
 })
.catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```